# router undefined in production build

Tags: ember.js

I created a new Ember-cli app (using versions 2.1 of Ember and Ember Data). It runs fine on the dev server, but in order to use it as a front-end to a WordPress app, I'm using the production builds for development of the WordPress. i.e. I'm running `Ember build` and linking vendor.js and `myemberapp.js` into the WordPress site on my localhost. When I run the WordPress site locally, I get this error in my console for Ember

```
"Cannot read property 'startRouting' of undefined"
```

Here, `undefined` refers to the router. ember.debug.js:3583 links to the `startRouting` function

```
  startRouting: function(){
     var router = +emberMetalProperty_get.get(this, 'router');
     router.startRouting(isResolverModuleBased(this);
     this._didSetupRouter = true;
  }
```

Also, in the function called before that funtion is `didBecomeReady`. I'm assuming that's somehow related to the DOM being ready but it's not entirely clear from the source.

No other errors like this on google...

Question: why might the router be `undefined` in the production build?

```
                Versions: Ember : 2.1.0
                Ember Data : 2.1.0
                JQuery: 1.11.3
```

Comment: Can you post your router.js?

Comment: Look for 404 errors in network tab of dev tools. Maybe some path on production is wrong

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 it's the default router code from an Ember 2.1.0 app with one route defined `this.route('posts', { path: '/'}, function(){  console.log("blah") }`. I'm just testing loading the Ember bundle into a WordPress app. The app works on dev server (i.e. no router error)

Comment: Are you running the app in the index page of Wordpress?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get the solution.